# failing to move image from gallery to sdcard after encrypting the image

Tags: android, encryption

I am trying to encrypt an image from the gallery and store it on the sdcard.

When i am trying to move the image from the gallery to the sdcard i am getting a "force close" error and logcat does not show an exception.

I am getting a toast saying "Image successfully encrypted" but it is not moving the image from the gallery to the sdcard.

What am i doing wrong?

```
        private void encript(byte[] data, byte[] clear) {

        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09,
        0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17 };
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = null;

        try {

        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding", "BC");

        }    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        }    catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(data.length)];

       // int ctLength = cipher.update(data, 0, data.length, cipherText, 0);

        byte[] input = null;

        try { 
        input = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block


        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
        if(input.length>0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image successfully encripted", 3000).show();
        }
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(input);

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);

     File encriptedfile = (File) ois.readObject();//This is the file which i want to Move to App folder

            bis.close();
        ois.close();
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
    return;
    }
     //Code for copy  image into app folder......
    File outputFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + ".map");
         try {
          FileUtils.copyFile (encriptedfile, outputFolder);
          } 
          catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e("photomover", e.toString());
          }
}
```

---

```
08-17 11:42:00.905: WARN/System.err(8453): java.io.StreamCorruptedException
08-17 11:42:00.905: WARN/System.err(8453):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2392)
08-17 11:42:00.905: WARN/System.err(8453):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:445)
08-17 11:42:00.905: WARN/System.err(8453):     at com.cw.GalleryShareimage1Activity.encript(GalleryShareimage1Activity.java:177)
08-17 11:42:00.905: WARN/System.err(8453):     at com.cw.GalleryShareimage1Activity.onCreate(GalleryShareimage1Activity.java:76)
08-17 11:42:00.915: WARN/System.err(8453):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-17 11:42:00.915: WARN/System.err(8453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
08-17 11:42:00.915: WARN/System.err(8453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
08-17 11:42:00.915: WARN/System.err(8453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
08-17 11:42:00.915: WARN/System.err(8453):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
08-17 11:42:00.915: WARN/System.err(8453):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-17 11:42:00.915: WARN/System.err(8453):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-17 11:42:00.915: WARN/System.err(8453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
08-17 11:42:00.915: WARN/System.err(8453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 11:42:00.915: WARN/System.err(8453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-17 11:42:00.915: WARN/System.err(8453):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-17 11:42:00.915: WARN/System.err(8453):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-17 11:42:00.915: WARN/System.err(8453):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-17 11:42:00.925: WARN/dalvikvm(8453): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207d8)
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cw/com.cw.GalleryShareimage1Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Source must not be null
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Source must not be null
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453):     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1068)
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453):     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1038)
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453):     at com.cw.GalleryShareimage1Activity.onCreate(GalleryShareimage1Activity.java:96)
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
08-17 11:42:00.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8453):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Step through your code and see what is going on. See where it is failing. Posting your logcat would also be helpful. (even though you are saying it is not showing an exception)

Comment: By getting encripted file name, am able to copy image into app folder but am unable to put encripted file to app folder....

Comment: Thanks for giving reply.....Ofter Some time i got "java.io.StreamCorruptedException"...how can i avoid this pls....give me any advise....

Comment: Very interesting, so you get data, then you encrypt to an internal buffer (this code is probably copied from somewhere) and then you throw away the result and say that the file is encrypted. And you encrypt function is called encript. I guess you need to learn to walk before starting to try and run.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as several flaws:

First, when you encrypt the data you are not processing the data to be encrypted correctly. You should try it this way:

```
byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(data);
```

Second you are using an `ObjectInputStream` and it's `readObject()` method. An ObjectInputStream is only useful for data that has been created by Java serialization. You can not process images this way. Casting it to `File` also doe not make any sense.

As you are performing everything in RAM (which will BTW not work for large files because of the RAM limitation on android) you just have to save the encrypted in-memory data to the file. No move necessary:

```
File outputFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),".map");
File outputFile = new File(outputFolder, "outputfilename.bin");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
out.write(cipherText);
out.close;
```

Comment: File outputFile = new File(outputFolder, imagename); when am giving file name dynamically am getting "FilenotFound Exception"  "outputfilename.bin"......wt is the problem...here....