# Saving draft emails in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-internet

I have an app from which we can send emails .I need some help with the email sending. If the the internet is not available need to store the mail and when connection available send the saved mails.Which is the effective option to save the draft mails ?(Like draft mail in gmail, where gmail stores draft mails ?) store db ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a db with encrypted e-mails using something like AES like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816771/android-encryption) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987641/failing-to-move-image-from-gallery-to-sdcard-after-encrypting-the-image).

Comment: Not really, I never tried to figure out that. But I think should be something like that, encrypt the messages and than save it on sd card, the saving method you can choose by yourself as a SQLite db or some custom file(s), maybe just saving a single encrypted file per draft is easier and faster.

Comment: you're welcome! When you got some results please share it with us

Answer (score 0):

If the the internet is not available, the device will try to send it when the internet is available again. Or you can download some Apps if you like.

Comment: sorry  what u mean by "your can download some Apps if u like."?